# Can 2 GIS layers which representing the same area be compared directly while having the same datum but different coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, comparison, catchment-area

My question is about how coordinate systems affect comparison of different layers - I have tried to refresh my memory about coordinate systems in GIS, but am still unsure about this situation.

I am comparing the land cover classifications (estimates of the % each land cover type represents in the given area) from a raster layer versus from a vector shape used in photo-interpretation. This comparison will be done on many raster-classification/photo-interpretation combinations throughout the United States.

The area of the vector layer comes from delineating a watershed (generally 25 to 250 square kilometers in area), and that delineation and vector layer is then used to clip that area out of a larger land classification raster layer.

The vector layers used in photo-interpretation are all in lat/long (unprojected). The photo-interpretation is already done, so I need to keep these source shapes as they are. These vector layers have the following coordinate system:

```
Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum: D_North_American_1983
```

All of the raster layers I'm working with have the following coordinate system:

```
Spatial Reference:  Albers_Conical_Equal_Area
Datum: D_North_American_1983
```

Are the areas of these 2 GIS layers the same, given they have the same Geographic Coordinate System, or am I in error to compare the vector layer to the raster layer, given that the vector layer is not projected and the raster layer is? 
If the latter, then can I simply project the vector layer to the same coordinate system as the vector layer, and if so can that be done *after* clipping the raster to the vector shape or must the projection be done before clipping?

Comment: You question mentions the "same PCS as the vector layer" but your vectors don't *have* a PCS, they have a GCS (*Geographic* coordinate system, not *Projected*). If you care about area, do *not* deproject the rasters.  Project the vector to Albers (the same *exact* Albers, since the projection differs with different parameters).  You can deproject (*carefully*) back to the GCS after analysis is complete.

Comment: Sorry about that confusion. I meant to say the raster is projected and the vector is not. I also mistook Spatial Reference for a Projected Coordinate System, and I need to learn more about the relationship between defining Spatial Reference and Projection.
Given the correction: can these layers be compared given they have the same GCS? Or are they not comparable because the raster layer has the Spatial Reference defined as Alberts whereas the vector layer has a GCS defined similar to the shared datum?

Comment: "Comparable" is not well-defined.  No modern GIS software would attempt comparison without on-the-fly projection, but successful *direct* comparison by old (or deficient) software is not possible.  Dynamic projection is computationally expensive (though not as expensive as dynamic NADCON), which is why you should just project the vector once and be done with it.

Comment: By compare I mean, analyze the difference in land cover classification between a method using the raster layer and a method using the vector layer. So, for them to be comparable, I need them to be representative of the same area (size, shape, location) on Earth.
It's still not clear to me if that kind of comparison can be done with these layers as they are. I want to avoid modifying the vector layer because photo-interpretation was already done on them, so I'm hoping to modify the raster layer so its equivalent to the vector area (the area that was already photo-interpreted).

Comment: Your rasters are in Albers conical equal area projection, even if they are based on the datum D_NA 1983. Effectively, your vector and raster are on a different coordinate system. In this case your rasters are projected but your vectors are on geographic coordinate system (they also have different units). So it would be best to project either the raster to the vector system or vice versa to do your spatial analysis.

Comment: Your want/hope cannot be realized.  Area comparison in Cartesian degrees is useless.  Deprojecting the rasters will warp them and render them unfit for comparison (each row of pixels will have a different area).  Photo interpretation done in a GCS coordsys is likely of questionable value; the areas would have to have been mensurated geodetically (which deprojecting should retain, but without the extra bother).  No projection can preserve size and shape perfectly (especially with respect to orientation), but an Albers over a large study area doesn't do an awful job.

Comment: I must say I second Vince, for area calculations, it is best to convert your vectors to the Albers EA projection. Apart from being appropriate it is easier to communicate your results in m2, km2, miles2 etc... rather than dec. deg.  squares, which nobody likes.

Comment: The land cover typing (including photo-interpretation) is just to get % estimates, not specific areas. The vector files are in GCS because the photo-interpretation was done using Google Maps imagery, so the shapefile defining the area being photo-interpreted needed to be in GCS.

Comment: Because the vector files have already been analyzed, I modified the raster's coordinate system so I could compare its land cover results with that of the photo-interpretation. I used the Project Raster tool and imported the coordinate system from the vector layer - the output raster has a Spatial Reference equal to the GCS of the vector (GCS_North_American_1983). The raster in Albers Conical has slightly different land cover type %s than that in GCS_North_American_1983. I think I'll use this method to match the raster and vector coordinate systems. Does that sound reasonable to you all?

Comment: It sounds like an incorrect procedure, for the reasons already given.

Comment: Why not project the rasters back to GCS then? If you are interested in %s only and won't need explicit units to report the result. To the least I'd go and re-project the rasters into geographic coordinate system (use your vectors to define the exact coordinate system you need for the rasters). Is there an explicit reason why you want to keep the rasters in albers equal area?

Comment: @yanes I did as you suggested. I don't care to keep the rasters in albers equal area. My goals are to keep the vectors in their original coordinate system to ensure the photo-interpreted land cover %s remain true to the shapefile; and to get the rasters in a coordinate system equivalent to the vectors so their land cover %s can be compared. So, I re-projected the raster layer into the GCS defined by the vector layer.

Comment: @cr0 I apologize for the repetition must have misunderstood you then. I don't reckon there is any problem with that method. Especially if you are reporting percentages.

Comment: @Vince I don't fully understand all the reasons you listed as I have only a basic understanding of coordinate systems. Is the issue with the procedure yanes & I described that raster pixels will be warped? Certainly reprojecting the raster from Albers conical to GCS_NA83 changed the cell size, cell count, and even distribution of cells in each land class slightly. Because I'm interested in the % of each land class of the raster compared to the % of land classes photo-interpreted from the vector, I think re-projecting the raster to the defined GCS of the vector will setup the best comparison.

Comment: In case it helps: the areas I am dealing with are mixed-use watersheds of approximately 25 to 250 square kilometers, spread throughout the United States.

Comment: The values you are struggling to preserve are the *incorrect* ones, warped by being in a GCS. The "areas" are sufficiently wrong as to make any analysis based on them *wrong*. Peer review would bear this out later; better to address it now.

Comment: @Vince which values would be the correct ones to preserve given the purpose of this is to compare the land cover class %s of raster data vs. photo-interpretation based on a vector shapefile, with both GIS layers representing the same ~25-250sq.km. watershed or municipal boundary?